# Format data entered in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

In the program you have to enter in scores for bowling for 4 players such as this:

> - Enter score number 1 for player John ---> 5
> - Enter score number 1 for player Bill ---> 7
> - Enter score number 1 for player Bob  ---> 8
> - Enter score number 1 for player Phil ---> 10

And it goes on for 10 scores for each player the same as it does above. What I am having trouble with is making a table to show current scores after each score is entered. It also has to update the total scores so far when a new score is updated that is shown on the far right. The table would look like this

[Picture of what table is to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiBmX.png)

**Here is my code so far.**

```
package bowling;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class bowling {

private static final int NUMBER_OF_ENDS = 10;
private static String[] player = new String[4];
private static int[][] scores = new int[4][NUMBER_OF_ENDS];

public static void addPlayer() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Enter player #" + counter + " name");
        player[counter] = input.nextLine();

    }
}

public static void addScores() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int inner = 0; inner < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; inner++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {

            System.out.print("Enter score number " + (inner + 1) + " score for " + player[counter] + "---->");
            scores[counter][inner] = input.nextInt();

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You could initialize the matrix with 0 for all scores. You can also have an extra array to keep track of the current score - that will just be a sum of all the scores so far for that player. This sum must be called after each insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a separate array to store the player totals, call it:

```
int[] totals = new int[4];
```

You could increment the total each time you add a new score:

```
scores[counter][inner] = score;
totals[counter] += score; // increment the total for that player
```

And you could write a method called `showScores()` that you call everytime you add a score, and increment a total:

```
scores[counter][inner] = score;
totals[counter] += score; // increment the total for that player
showScores();
```

In that method you will need to:

- iterate over each player
- print the name from the `players` array, and then iterate over the `scores` array for that player and print each of their scores, and then use the same player index to print their total score from the `totals` array.

I'll leave that part to you as it's not any more difficult that what you have already written, it's just a slightly different nested loop. Make it print out the correct data, and then work on the formatting later.